# Laravel: accessing url multiple time with different parameter returns wrong data

Tags: laravel, server, laravel-routing, laravel-request, laravel-response

The view of my application post data to controller with a parameter in URL. The URL is like

```
   xxxx/admin/shipments/edit/50
```

It means I am editing the shipment having shipment_id = 50. but when user uses the application after certain time instead of respective shipment_id that is 50. It returns the data of other shipments such as 56, 51, 90 etc.

```
    public function routeShipmentsEdit($shipment_id){ 
    // Numeric Check
    If(is_numeric($shipment_id)){}
```

Comment: Your codes are very unclear. Please post some useful codes to review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was server caching. The page size was more than 4k therefore the server was caching it and was always returning the cached page. I managed to reduce the size of page and now its working fine.